# Appending to a copied list appends to the original

Tags: list, assign

I am a newbie to Python, so find this a little perplexing. In my code, I have a list of strings:

```
a=['One','Two','Three','Four']
```

I want to use this list in a function call, later, but need to use a slightly modified list for a function call before that. So, what do I do? I make a copy of a, preserving it presumably.

```
b=a
b.append('Five')
```

Now I happily use b, without affecting a, correct? No, it seems that I was wrong, and a gets "infected" with whatever I did to b.

```
print(a)
['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five']
```

This was the cause of a major bug in some analysis code I was writing. Took me an hour to track down. This suggests that the assignment b=a only makes the pointer of b to point to a, but does not create a copy (the way I am used to in Fortran 95, and Matlab).

How does one copy a list to another one, while leaving the original unmolested?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I need to use the copy() function: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/copy.

Comment: Yes, just assigning a list to another doesn't create a new list in memory, it's just a reference to the same location. This is known as shallow copy. Using `copy()` allows you to create a new list in memory known as deep copy.

Answer (score 0):

Python supports dynamic memory allocation. You are storing value of a into b but what happens is, the address of b and a becomes same. You can check it using id() function like this:-

```
a=['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
b=a
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

So, what you can do is you can use .copy() function that creates copy of a list and store that in another variable that will be stored at different address.
the changes you will make into the copied list will no more affect the original list because both are stored at two different locations.

```
a = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
b = a.copy()
b.append('five')
print(a)
print(b)
```

output:-
    ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four']
    ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'five']